# Push new data to array, if indices match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a variable called "animeData" that contains an array of objects.

```
{"table":[{"id":1,"name":"K-on","redirect":"k-on","thumbnail":"/images/anime/k-on/thumbnail.jpg","characters":[{"name":"azusa","thumbnail":"/images/anime/k-on/azusa.jpg","votes":[{"ip":"127.0.0.1"}]},{"name":"mio","thumbnail":"/images/anime/k-on/mio.jpg","votes":[{}]},{"name":"mugi","thumbnail":"/images/anime/k-on/mugi.jpg","votes":[{}]},{"name":"ritsu","thumbnail":"/images/anime/k-on/ritsu.jpg","votes":[{}]},{"name":"yui","thumbnail":"/images/anime/k-on/yui.jpg","votes":[{}]}]},{"id":2}]}
```

I am trying to add a new set of information, under the ID 2, like I did for 1, starting with the name.
I have tried `animeData.table.filter(x => x.id === 2).push({"name": "Bunny Girl Senpai"});`
However, there are no errors in the console but nor does the "animeData" var change.

Comment: the `animeData` won't be changed, `Array.prototype.filter()` returns a new array

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve. Do you want to push a new character to the characters array? Or change the name of a table with id 2?

Comment: I am trying to add a new set of information (name, redirect, thumbnail, characters) but under the ID 2, so completely seperate to the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter()` according to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array.

What you probably want to use is `Array.prototype.find()` instead, which according to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Since `find()` is going to return an object, I think you would also just want to set the `name` property instead of pushing it. Something like this:

```
animeData.table.find(x => x.id === 2)["name"] = "Bunny Girl Senpai";
```

Be careful with `find()` method, if it is not able to find an element it will return undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` method of an array returns an array containing the filtered elements, it is an array of objects. As we get the single object in an array then we can go for that object with array indexing as `filteredData[0]`. As it is an object then we can set the property of an object using `.` notation or `[]` syntax. Both are valid.

```js
const animeData = {
  table: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "K-on",
      redirect: "k-on",
      thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/thumbnail.jpg",
      characters: [
        {
          name: "azusa",
          thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/azusa.jpg",
          votes: [{ ip: "127.0.0.1" }],
        },
        { name: "mio", thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/mio.jpg", votes: [{}] },
        { name: "mugi", thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/mugi.jpg", votes: [{}] },
        {
          name: "ritsu",
          thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/ritsu.jpg",
          votes: [{}],
        },
        { name: "yui", thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/yui.jpg", votes: [{}] },
      ],
    },
    { id: 2 },
  ],
};

const idToSearch = 2;
const filteredData = animeData.table.filter((x) => x.id === 2);
if (filteredData.length) {
  const filteredObject = filteredData[0];
  filteredObject["name"] = "Bunny Girl Senpai";
}
console.log(animeData);
```

or with `find`

```js
const animeData = {
  table: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "K-on",
      redirect: "k-on",
      thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/thumbnail.jpg",
      characters: [
        {
          name: "azusa",
          thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/azusa.jpg",
          votes: [{ ip: "127.0.0.1" }],
        },
        { name: "mio", thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/mio.jpg", votes: [{}] },
        { name: "mugi", thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/mugi.jpg", votes: [{}] },
        {
          name: "ritsu",
          thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/ritsu.jpg",
          votes: [{}],
        },
        { name: "yui", thumbnail: "/images/anime/k-on/yui.jpg", votes: [{}] },
      ],
    },
    { id: 2 },
  ],
};

const idToSearch = 2;
const search = animeData.table.find((anime) => anime.id === 2);
search["name"] = "TemporaryName";
search["redirect"] = "temp";
console.log(animeData);
```